# Calibre does not detect Kobo CLara 2E

Tags: calibre

I have bought a KOBO Clara 2E ereader. So far i have been unable to connect it to Calibre. I have also been unable to find a solution on the Internet, though there are lots op people who did say something about it. FYI: The ereader is visible in the file manager, so it is mounted. I have the latest version of Ubuntu (22.04.2) LTS installed

Comment: It seems that the problem is the ereader being mounted as a MTP device instead of a mass storage device. If that is indeed so, how do I get the Kobo Clara 2E mounted as a mass storage device? I have read somethings (https://superuser.com/questions/1206664) about changing the udev rules but have not been able to find out which file with extension .rules I should change

Answer (score 1):

Support for Kobo Clara 2E was [added to Calibre in version 6.5](https://calibre-ebook.com/whats-new), so I was able to fix this issue by using the Snap installation of Calibre, which has a newer version than `apt`. The version installed by `apt` was 5.37, as one can see in [Ubuntu packages for 22.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/calibre) but the version installed by Snap was 7.something. As soon as I installed the newer version, it worked.

To install Calibre as a Snap, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo snap install calibre
```